# Migration of data and upgrading from Bitnami GitLab 8.9.6 to latest GitLab CE omnibus

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, rhel, bitnami

Since Bitnami stopped Centos installer and started to support only ova, we are stuck with old version, Looking for document which talks about migrating Bitnami Gitlab to Latest Gitlab CE omnibus. We use external dbs.

Comment: Downvoter: Questions about programming tools (like GitLab) are explicitly on-topic here. Furthermore, there are plenty of recent questions about GitLab. Just because the OP says he is looking for a document doesn't mean this is instantly off-topic looking for external resource. You may be looking for a document but not find on, which brings us to the purpose Stack Overflow.

Comment: The fact he mentioned tools does not automatically make his question  about tools.

Answer (score 1):

In this link you can find the process a user followed to upgrade Gitlab from non-omnibus to omnibus: https://community.bitnami.com/t/migration-of-data-and-upgrading-from-bitnami-gitlab-7-10-1-to-latest-gitlab-enterprise-version/46741/12?u=jsalmeron

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitLab backup/restore docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html):

> You can only restore a backup to **exactly the same version and type (CE/EE)** of GitLab on which it was created. The best way to migrate your repositories from one server to another is through backup restore.

Here's what I would do:

- Create a full backup of the old GitLab instance using the rake task
- Install a new instance of GitLab 8.9.6 in your new server (using Omnibus distro package)
- Restore the backup to your new server
- Slowly upgrade your new server to the latest version

  - I would only skip about 2-4 minor versions at a time, and recommend going back through and reading the release notes of each version.
  - E.g. `yum install gitlab-ce-9.1.0`